# Should "How do I ask a good question?" be more specific?

Tags: discussion

[How do I ask a good question?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) gives this advice:

> **Be specific**
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.

That section is ... vague.  Is it time to revisit that section of the help center and add a *bit* more information to help newcomers to the site write better questions?  It doesn't need to be as wordy as I would be (see [Crafting an Irresistible Research Question](http://www.theancestorhunt.com/blog/crafting-an-irresistible-research-question)), but I feel we could help newcomers out a little more than this.

Possibly relevant prior discussions:

- [How much context should be supplied in a question about an individual?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1268/1006)
- [What information needs to be included in a question to demonstrate its genealogical interest?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1960/1006)
- [How should I react to a question that "appears" to show no prior research?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1695/1006)
- [How do I know that I have a good question?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1290/1006)

Answer (score 1):

Suggested change in boldface:

"If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, **such as a locality and a date range**, we can provide a useful answer."

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks -- I can never remember which pages we're allowed to edit and not edit.  Another friend who is a user of SE suggested that I include a copy of the material from http://www.theancestorhunt.com/blog/crafting-an-irresistible-research-question on G&FH SE itself so there would be a backup copy in case my host's site went down. I'd like to have something here I could refer users to, especially my further reading list where people gave specific advice about writing specific questions, which had to be scrapped for the guest post.

Comment: There's now a Meta SE Q&A about the Help pages we can change at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331026/is-the-help-center-content-identical-on-all-sites-in-the-stack-exchange-network

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that it is time to revisit our Help Center and its help on how to ask questions.

Unfortunately, we cannot edit [How do I ask a good question?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), but there is a Meta Q&A hoping to change that at [Customize the How To Ask page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330218/customize-the-how-to-ask-page).

In the meantime, we could do something now like what is done at the GIS Stack Exchange by using a link from its https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic page to a Meta GIS SE Q&A titled: [Asking good Questions for GIS Stack Exchange?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange)

I proposed similar wording, tailored to G&FH SE, in [an answer](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2088/19) on this Meta to [Dealing with broad questions that ask for "any information about <person/family/etc>"?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/dealing-with-broad-questions-that-ask-for-any-information-about-person-family)

I think we should draw from many sources to try and achieve an "Asking good Questions for G&FH SE?" that includes content from your blog, my answer and other contributors by using this Q&A to assess the need, and if that need is agreed then starting a Community Wiki Meta Q&A on "Wording `<whatever we call it>` for linking into our Help Center?"

Comment: This is probably the right way to go about it -- and could subsume the question aspects of https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3427/would-a-meta-question-about-citation-expectations-be-useful-here as well.  Remind me, do we have any way to customise 'good answer' guidance in a similar way?

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl it can be linked in at the same spot and in the same way - it’s the only help page that offers moderators an edit button.

Comment: Not ideal, but might be the best we can do short term.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl There is also a section on the [front page of the Help Center](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help) where we can edit above the **Find out more about...** title.  I only became aware of it recently: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331029/215590